# Why use try and catch() in C++?

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

I understand that `try` and `catch()` are used for exception handling, just in case an error or crash would occur in the program under certain cases. I also understand how they work. But why use `try` and `catch()`? Why not just use an `if()` statement that looks for a certain case and if that case is true, it does `cout << //error code`?

Comment: There are no parentheses associated with the `try` keyword. In fact, `catch` doesn't always have it, either.

Comment: @MarceloCantos: "In fact, catch doesn't always have [parentheses], either" - yes it does - from S15.1: "handler:
catch ( exception-declaration ) compound-statement" - there is no other legal syntax.

Comment: @TonyD: D'oh! I confused it with C# (too many languages in my head).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Exception handling:

- can be used with constructors and operators that have no opportunity to return a separate error code (they could set the object into some error state - which implies further memory usage - but the client code also has to remember to check for that error state later)

  - for example: user defined type - class `X` - supports notation `x1 = x2 + x3` - where could an error code be returned?
- can kick in as a specific class/struct data member is constructed in an initialiser list - avoiding further data member construction that may then be doomed or wasteful; by way of contrast, explicit error handling is only possible later in the constructor body
- is more implicit - emphasising the normal successful flow of code, which can make it more concise, readable, maintainable
- is factored differently - exceptions from many places can be caught in one place, which sometimes makes the error handling code itself more concise, readable, maintainable
- concision benefits can actually lead to more reliable error handling in cases where the error handling would otherwise be repetitious
- typically use their own memory area, independent of the stack used for local variables, function parameters, saving CPU registers and return addresses etc.; this means a throw statement may be able to reliably construct the exception object directly in that memory area even when remaining stack memory is smaller than the exception object (though that an implementation detail and not guaranteed by the Standard)
- has a different performance profile, such that either can be faster in certain circumstances
- facilitates propagation of richer error information from low level code up through intermediate code, which you may not "own" or want/be-able to change to propagate error codes C-style, to the point of handling

Comment: -1 "use its own stack which means error handling can be reliable in stack-overflow scenarios" is [bullshit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bullshit#Distinguished_from_lying)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: a link to something related to the technical assertion you're objecting to is more useful than you trying to impress us with some pretentious nuances you'd like to ascribe to "bullshit"

Comment: your statement ""use its own stack which means error handling can be reliable in stack-overflow scenarios" is pure bullshit. c++ exception handling doesn't use its own stack, and that's not meaningful. it is not reliable in stack overflow situations: the language makes no guarantees for that situation. in short, again, it's utter bullshit. a fantasy similar **in form** to a technical statement, but where the content is -- just bullshit.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Standard 15.1.4 "The memory for the exception object is allocated in an unspecified way, except as noted in 3.7.4.1." - which doesn't require a separate stack, but is there precisely because typical implementations provide a separate stack.  *The exception object lifetime is unrelated to the main stack - so how do you think the allocation is done?*.  Use your brain and read between the lines a bit!

Comment: Re "stack overflow scenarios" specifically, what I'm saying is that given say 1k remaining stack, and a throw statement trying to create an exception object that's 10k in size, it may well work given the simple optimisation of in-place construction.  I agree the Standard doesn't promise any specific optimisations, but that doesn't make the potential bullshit.  I'll reword the answer to use this specific scenario rather than the vague "stack-overflow scenarios".

Comment: exception objects are not allocated on the stack. stack overflow has no guaranteed behavior. you claims are all just bullshit.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: "not allocated on the stack" - I said a seperate stack not "the stack" where "the" implies alongside local variables etc..  If you don't read carefully, you'll end up with bullshit.  I've elaborated to clarify the specific scenario that's different for exceptions versus returning error values - that you may be able to return a larger object that would fit on "the" stack as the exception object can be expected to be elsewhere.  None of that is bullshit.  Note that the behaviour described is about avoiding a stack overflow, not behaviour after one.  Also, you're a rude git.

Comment: Exceptions are allocated the same way as unicorns... It's all about rainbows... Keep calm guys...

Answer (score 5):

`try...catch` does more. It unwinds the stack which calls the destructors for all automatically allocated objects since the `try` was entered. If you do it your suggested way you'll have to keep track of these object manually or you'll get memory issues (leaks, overwriting, stale pointers, double deletes)

Comment: That's not true at all... if functions return error codes rather than exceptions, the `if (error) return` logic in the caller will also bubble the error up invoking the same destructors.  If there are raw pointers that need deallocation, exceptions won't magically arrange that deallocation.

Comment: It's actually true. Without a `try...catch` statement, throwing an exception might not unwind the stack. (15.5.1)

Comment: @MSalters: of course that's true if exceptions may be thrown, but the question is asking "Why not just use an if() statement that looks for a certain case and if that case is true, it does cout << //error code?"... in other words, C-style return code propagation... and compared to that being done exclusively "try...catch does more" is not true.

Answer (score 1):

The other reason is: code you write might as well be used as a part of larger project by somebody else. And since using built-in exception-handling routines is a standard, maintainers of the larger project are expecting that you handle your exceptions likewise, so that exception handling can be properly fulfilled at upper levels - not to speak of the fact, that using standard output as an error output is a dubious practice (it may be suppressed, for example; or not be used at all).

UPD: I misunderstood your question a little bit. The reason I described actually justifies manual exception throwing, but not using `try...catch` blocks.

Answer (score -2):

I'm going to answer with a quote from one of my heroes, Martin Sústrik of ZeroMQ fame, taken from a blog entry at http://www.250bpm.com/blog:4

> However, what's great for avoiding straightforward failures becomes a nightmare when your goal is to guarantee that no undefined behaviour happens. The decoupling between raising of the exception and handling it, that makes avoiding failures so easy in C++, makes it virtually impossible to guarantee that the program never runs info undefined behaviour.

And then add, I find I use try/catch for very high lever restart layers, more than anything else.  Adding, that my opinion really doesn't matter.  I'm of the belief that the choice behind how and why to use exception handling is very similar to the *choice* of liking green more than blue.  Personal, and no input from others is ever likely to change it.

Comment: Nonsense quote. There's no reason at all why exceptions cause UB, and there's are one important reason why they prevent UB: they cause a quick exit from parts of the code that are incompatible with your data.

Answer (score -2):

The question poses a **false dichotomy**. In Java and C# `try`-`catch` competes with `if` for cleanup on failure. In C++ it's mainly RAII technique (using destructors and single phase construction) that competes with `if` for cleanup on failure.

If the question had been about using exceptions versus using `if`, then it would have been more sensible and relevant to ordinary C++ programming.

Comment: "If the question had been about using exceptions versus using if, then [sensible]" - how is that substantively different from the question: "...why use try and catch()? Why not just use an if()..."?

Comment: You know, strangely, I did.  But, comparisons with Java and C# (neither of which were mentioned in the question or tags) doesn't set this up to comprehensible for the likely audience.  Anyway, if it works for you and you have nothing more to say, that's fine by me.

Comment: @TonyD: you could read the answer that you're commenting on. you seem to have severe reading comprehension problems and a *very* lively fantasy. i suggest you turn off the fantasy circuit and read slowly.'

Comment: Ok, whatever Alf.  Hope you have a better day tomorrow.