# error_code vs errno

Tags: c++, c++11, error-handling, errno

I am studying C++11 standards. I wanted to understand if error_code and errno related to each other? If yes then how?
If no then in which conditions i should expect errno to be set and in which conditions error_code will be set?

I did a small test program to understand this but still little confused. Please help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <system_error>
#include <thread>
#include <cstring>
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    try
    {
        thread().detach();
    } catch (const system_error & e) {
        cout<<"Error code value - "<<e.code().value()<<" ; Meaning - "<<e.what()<<endl;
        cout<<"Error no. - "<<errno<<" ; Meaning - "<<strerror(errno)<<endl;
    }
}

Output -
Error code value - 22 ; Meaning - Invalid argument
Error no. - 0 ; Meaning - Success
```

Comment: Your title refers to something called `error_code`, but your code doesn't mention it.

Comment: @Keith : e.code() function returns object of error_code whose value i am reading with value function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`errno` is used by the those functions that document that as a side effect of their encountering an error - those functions are C library or OS functions that never throw exceptions.  `system_error` is a used by the C++ Standard Library for when you're using library facilities documented to throw that exception.  Completely separate.  Ultimately, read your docs!

Comment: So can we conveniently say that those library functions who sets error_code will never use/set errno?

Comment: @tshah06 `error_code` is not "set". It's the type(def) of an attribute of the `system_error` exception. But we can conveniently say that library functions *that throw a `system_error` exception* never use/set `errno`. This duality exists only because you can call C-functions (doing C-style error handling via `errno`) from C++. In "pure" C++ exceptions are the error handling mechanism of choice, so a "pure" C++ program will never have to deal with `errno`.

Comment: @Arne : Make sense. I think now i'm pretty much clear about it. Thanks.

Comment: @Arne : One more query. If exceptions are error handling mechanism in C++, then a pure C++ function should never report an error in the form of return code and should always throw an exception if it failed?

Comment: @tshah06 yes, it should. But meanwhile, the definition of "failure" is a completely different descussion ;-) sometimes it's enough to just return "special case" objects. But the case with exceptions is that you just call a function and use its return types, *without* having to check for som error conditions (`errno`, returned flags or nullpointers) first. There are C++ projects that use other types of error handling than exceptions, and it's perfectly viable (if used consistently) to do so, but it's not what pursists would consider "pure" C++.

Comment: @tshah06: you might find this question/answer informative: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14866791/why-use-try-and-catch-in-c/14866866#14866866

Comment: @tshah06 - it makes me nervous whenever someone talks about "pure" C++; it usually means an ideological rather than an engineering perspective. C++ is a multiple-paradigm language, and good engineering means choosing the most appropriate approach to solving a problem, without regard to notions of "pure" versus "impure". Some functions return error codes; some set global flags; some functions throw exceptions; some functions abort the program. The choice depends on what the error is, what the appropriate response is, and whether the calling code could deal with it. But errno **is** weird.

Comment: @Ame: neither exceptions are "the" error handling mechanism in C++, nor a "pure" function should only ever throw an exception. For example, in the Standard C++ already some functions that operate on strings will do things such as return -1 for index errors instead of throwing an exception, and other facilities form ``<system_error>`` than error_code are defined to host and copy error codes instead of running exception paths, such as ``error_condition``.  "Only exceptions" is a battlecry of a zealot faction of C++ developers, ultimately.